# How to delay server from running before Tests run

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I've been trying to get around writing  functional tests for my services using `jest`.

The action in the tests gets resolved but the test never passed because it keeps complaining that the **server is already in use**.

```
 startServer()

  describe("api tests", () => {
  it("createUser: should create user successfully", async () => { 
    const user = await createUserService(userCredentials)
     expect(user.email).toBe("test2@test.com")
  }, 12000)

})
```

If i check my database, the user actually gets created in the process but for some reasons the tests does't pass and it return an error saying `port address in use`.

I have also tried to call `startServer()` in jest's `beforeAll(() => {})`. It still returns the same behaviour.

Comment: You should remove the config to run in parallel and after each test you should close the server an alternative would be to have random startServer(randomNumber) this way the conflict chances would reduce and afterAll add stopServer so that the server is closed

Comment: Thank you for your comment. please, what do you mean by remove config?

Comment: https://www.testim.io/blog/supertest-how-to-test-apis-like-a-pro/ you should give it a try you'll need to change the way you're thinking